# SQLite FOREIGN KEY type-name

Tags: sql, sqlite

The SQLite syntax documentation shows that a "type-name" can be specified when declaring a foreign key.

https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-def.html

I have not been able to find anywhere, what role it has with the "type" of the key that is refers to. What happen when the foreign key "type-name" does not match the "type-name" of the value it refers to? Does it play any role at all, or just for readability?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key constraint definition does not contain a type name. It can be attached to a column definition, which can have a type name, but that type name belongs to the column itself:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    ID    INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
    Name  TEXT,
    [...]
);
CREATE TABLE Child (
    [...],
    ParentID  INTEGER  REFERENCES Parent(ID)
    -- column def. --  ---- foreign key ----
);
```

All three columns shown above have a type, but the foreign key constraint begins with the `REFERENCES` and does not contain a type.

A foreign key constraint can also be written as a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Child (
    ParentID  INTEGER,
    [...],
    FOREIGN KEY ParentID REFERENCES Parent(ID)
);
```

This form makes it obvious that there is no separate type for the constraint.

---

Anyway, SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and ignores the type name in most circumstances, so it does not matter what you write in there, or if you're using a type at all.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It has caused me to look into my problem with a better perspective.

You mentioned, "It can be attached to a column definition, which can have a type name, but that type name belongs to the column itself"

You used:

ParentID  INTEGER  REFERENCES Parent(ID)

I do not understand the role that INTEGER has in this. It could be written as:

ParentID  REFERENCES Parent(ID)

with no Apparent change in behavior.

Any subtle reasons why someone would want to declare the type if it has no role? Does it have a purpose that I cannot detect?

Comment: SQlite actually uses the type for [affninity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), but in most cases, the type is just documentation.

Comment: Thanks...great info